# Uniform convergence of a series of functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been asked to discuss the uniform convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z}{n(1+nz^2)}$$

on the set $E = \{z = x+iy : 0 < y < x\}$.

I think the series converges on compact subsets of $E$ since we can bound the tail end quite nicely, but I don't know if I'm expected to say more than that.

Comment: what do you mean when you say $E = \{z = x+iy : 0 < y < z\}$ do you mean $E = \{z = x+iy : 0 < y < x\}$??

Comment: Edit and show your calculations here.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z}{n(1+nz^2)}=0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z}{n(1+nz^2)}=0
$$

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how does this help? Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned that you can show that the convergence is uniform on compact subsets. So for a given $\epsilon\gt0$, the basic idea is that we can find an $M$ so that for $|z|\ge M$ and $|z|\le1/M$, we have $\left|\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z}{n(1+nz^2)}\right|\le\epsilon$. For $\{z:1/M\lt|z|\lt M\}$, we have that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z}{n(1+nz^2)}$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Actually, defining $f(z) = \frac{z}{1+z^2}$, the series becomes $\sum \frac{f(\sqrt{n}z)}{n^{3/2}}$. We know that $f(\sqrt{n}z)$ is bounded on $E$, and so Weierstrass M-test shows that the series is uniformly convergent. I think this works?

Comment: @user125084: Indeed. For $z\in E$, it is easy to see that $|z+i|\gt1$: since $y\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
|z+i|^2
&=x^2+(y+1)^2\\
&=x^2+2y^2+2y+1\\
&\gt1
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, $|z-i|\gt\frac1{\sqrt2}|z|$: since $x\gt y\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
|z-i|^2-\tfrac12|z|^2
&=x^2+(y-1)^2-\tfrac12(x^2+y^2)\\
&=\tfrac12x^2+\tfrac12y^2-2y+1\\
&\gt y^2-2y+1\\
&=(y-1)^2\\
&\ge0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, on $E$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{z}{z^2+1}\right|
&=\frac1{|z+i|}\frac{|z|}{|z-i|}\\
&\lt1\cdot\sqrt2
\end{align}
$$